# PySpark: apply regex to remove unwanted text and make input a valid JSON

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file that unfortunately has some unwanted text in front of each line:

```
2019-07-02T22:53:16.848Z LOGFILE {"key":{"host":"example1.net","srcIP":"1.0.0.0","dstIp":"2.0.0.0"},"count":4,"last_seen":"2019-07-02T22:48:15.362Z"}
2019-07-02T22:53:16.937Z LOGFILE {"key":{"host":"example2.net","srcIP":"1.0.0.1","dstIp":"2.0.0.1"},"count":2,"last_seen":"2019-07-02T22:53:07.018Z"}
......
```

I would like to load this file as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext

spark = SparkSession \
       .builder \
       .appName("LogParser") \
       .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.json('log_sample.json')
```

but need a way to remove those unwanted text, for instance, `2019-07-02T22:53:16.848Z LOGFILE` to make it a valid JSON first. Would you shed some light on how to apply a regex before I can call `sqlContext.read.json()`? Otherwise it would complain it as a `_corrupt_record`. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have to use textFile to load whole file and then split string to json then create DataFrame from it.

Below snippet can be useful

```
log_path = './log.txt'

# Load each line to pair rdd
pair_rdd = sc.textFile(log_path)

# Split str from pair rdd and create new rdd of json string
# You can do more thing with it
json_rdd = pair_rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(' LOGFILE ')[1])

# Convert json rdd to DF
original_df = hive_context.read.json(json_rdd)

original_df.printSchema()
```

Comment: I figured it using `json_rdd = pair_rdd.map(lambda x: re.sub(r"^.* ","", x))` based on your solution. Thanks for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Read file with space delimited, drop first 2 columns and save again to json. Try if this works for you.

```
df=spark.read.csv("file.json",sep=" ").drop("_c0","_c1")

df.write.json("yourjasonfile.json")
```